# How to get name of closed rooms in Photon Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

When fetching list of rooms I am not able to get a room that is closed.

```
RoomInfo[] rooms = PhotonNetwork.GetRoomList();
```

In this when I iterate through list of rooms I only get the rooms that are currently open so when I try to create a new room and it is equal to the name of the closed room I get an error that the game id already exists. If my room was open I could always add a 1 to the existing list of rooms length but I need to close a room so other players can't join when the room is full. In doing so I am encountering this problem where game id already exists. Is there a way to get list of ALL rooms regardless of them being open or close so I can get a length of all the rooms thereby helping me create a new room if all others are closed?

Here is my current code for room joining:

```
 private void CreateOrJoinGame(eTable nameRoom)
{
    Invoke("ForceQuit", 8);
    panelLoad.SetActive(true);
    print("In progress joining or creating");
    RoomInfo[] rooms = PhotonNetwork.GetRoomList();
    PlayerSave.singleton.currentTable = nameRoom;
    for (int i = 0; i < rooms.Length; i++)
    {
        if (rooms[i].Name.Contains(nameRoom.ToString()) && rooms[i].PlayerCount < rooms[i].MaxPlayers)
        {
            PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(rooms[i].Name);
            return;
        }
    }
    RoomOptions roomOption = new RoomOptions() { IsVisible = true, MaxPlayers = 5 };
    PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(nameRoom.ToString() + rooms.Length + 1, roomOption, TypedLobby.Default);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says in the `<summary>` tag of `GetRoomList()` the following:

> Closed rooms are also listed by lobbies but they can't be joined.

Make sure you're connected to a lobby.

Comment: I am connected to a lobby and I do get list of available rooms but for some weird reason it does not list a closed room. No idea why

Comment: My bad. I had set the room visibility to false after room was full. Rectified. Thanks!